# create a hash from an array in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array in a specific order, and wish to create a hash with the odd numbered entries of the array as indexes and the even as values. This code does it perfectly, but leaves out one pair of values from the array.

```
    resolv_hash = Hash[*namerslv_array]
            puts "values in hash"
            resolv_hash.each do |key, array|
            puts "#{key}   " + array
            end
```

can anyone help with this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
resolv_hash = namerslv_array.each_slice(2).to_h
```

Illustration:

```
>> array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
>> array.each_slice(2).to_h
=> {1=>2, 3=>4, 5=>6, 7=>8, 9=>0}
```

Comment: That works, but still misses a pair or entries... my code output gives   * file[/etc/resolv.conf] action create_if_missing (up to date)
  * aix_etcresolv[nameserver] action add  values in array
nameserver
192.10.201.1
domain
abc.aus.century.com
nameserver
176.111.1.1
values in hash
nameserver   176.111.1.1
domain   abc.aus.century.com
where my file contents is 
cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver     192.10.201.1
domain  abc.aus.century.com
nameserver     176.111.1.1

Comment: Yes, that would do it. Keys are by definition unique, so trying to add an element to a Hash with an existing key instead results in replacement of that key's value with the new value. If you need duplicate keys/first values, you could use `namerslv_array.each_slice(2)` and store your data as array pairs instead of a hash.